# Calculating ECG leads from any two leads in MatLab

Tags: matlab

The six frontal leads of the ECG (I,II,III,aVR,aVL,aVF) can be calculated from any two leads. I would like to derive all signals from any combination of two signals.

The relationships are as follows:

```
II = I + III
aVR = -(I + II)/2
aVL = I – II/2
aVF = II – I/2
```

This is simple to do for a single sample using MatLab's solve function, but that seems to be an extremely inefficient method for long signals. What I would like to accomplish is to find the relationship between any two input signals and an output signal in order to efficiently compute the output. Is there a way to do this without manually deriving equations for each combination?

Answer (score 0):

To "find the relationship between any two input signals and an output signal" you've to make a **neural network** with two input time series and four output time series and train it with sufficient data.